# VBA Split Workbook into multiple workbooks based on cell value

Tags: vba, excel

I have a workbook with over 200 worksheets.  Each worksheet has salesmen name in cell M4.  I want to create a macro that loops through each worksheet and splits the master workbook into separate workbooks for each salesmen name based on the value in M4, so I can email it to them separately.  I figure it would be easier if I had an array with each salesmen name.  Can anyone assist me with a code that can do this process?   To further explain in my current workbook salesmen 1 has 5 worksheets with their name in M4, Salesmen 2 has 3 worksheets with their name in cell M4.  So for each Salesmen I want to move all worksheets into one file and than save it.

Comment: What have you tried so far? What has/hasn't worked? Basically, you just want to take each worksheet and put it in its own workbook, saved as the name in `M4`?

Comment: @BruceWayne I recorded myself but all it does is says sheet name("Blank").select and move.  To answer your second question Yes, I want to move each sheet based on M4 and save the file based on the name in M4

Comment: Yeah, the macro to do this would not be too long. Post the code you've tried so far. Also look up looping through worksheets. You'll just want to loop through each worksheet in your workbook, copy as new file, and save as value in M4.

Comment: @BruceWayne had do I group sheets that have the same salesmen?

Comment: Create a two-dimensional array of the Value in M4. One dimension is that name, the second is the sheet name.  Then, just sort the array by the name, and save equivalent sheets from there in a new workbook.  But please show what you've tried so far, as SO isn't a "code for me" site, but rather "help me with my code".

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
Sub WayEatFresh()

For i = 1 To ThisWorkbook.Sheets.Count
  NewWorkbookName = ThisWorkbook.Sheets(i).Cells(4, 13).Value
  ThisWorkbook.Sheets(i).Copy
  ActiveWorkbook.SaveAs "C:\YourFilePath\" & NewWorkbookName & ".xlsx", FileFormat:=51
Next

End Sub
```

EDIT:

```
Sub WayEatFresh()

Salesmen = ""
For i = 1 To ThisWorkbook.Sheets.Count
   If InStr(Salesmen, ThisWorkbook.Sheets(i).Cells(4, 13).Value) = 0 Then
    If Salesmen = "" Then
      Salesmen = ThisWorkbook.Sheets(i).Cells(4, 13).Value
    Else
      Salesmen = Salesmen & "->" & ThisWorkbook.Sheets(i).Cells(4, 13).Value
    End If
  End If
Next

SalesmanArray = Split(Salesmen, "->")

For i = 0 To UBound(SalesmanArray)
    NewWorkbookName = SalesmanArray(i)
    Set NewWB = Workbooks.Add
    For j = 1 To ThisWorkbook.Sheets.Count
        If ThisWorkbook.Sheets(j).Cells(4, 13).Value = SalesmanArray(i) Then
            ThisWorkbook.Sheets(j).Copy After:=NewWB.Sheets(1)
        End If
    Next

    NewWB.SaveAs ("C:\YourLocation\" & NewWorkbookName & ".xlsx")
    NewWB.Close
    Set NewWB = Nothing
Next

End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks but I don't think your understanding my question each Salesmen have multiple worksheets attributed to them.  Your current code is just saving every worksheet based on the value in M4.  I first want to create workbooks that have all worksheets with the same salesmen in them, than save it. @BYates

Comment: Check it out now. The workbook will have a blank sheet at the beginning but if you need to you can delete it at the end or something.

Comment: Thanks @BYates you saved me so much time thanks a million.

Comment: Glad to help. Though as BruceWayne mentioned, it's better if you provide code others can help you with rather than requesting code...but we can let this one slide :)